# Cocoapods inherit in post_install

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Is there a way to `inherit! :search_paths` in every target with condition? In my case I need to do it in every Test target.

For example:

```rb
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name.include? "Test"
      inherit! :search_paths
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Is your example code not working?